# multiple arguments to CreateThread function

Tags: c++, createthread

When I use the CreateThread API method, what do I need to do when I want to
pass more than one parameter where LPVOID lpParameter is passed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a structure that holds all relevant data and pass a pointer to an instance of that structure (filled with the appropriate parameters) to `CreateThread()`

In your thread creation function you will need to cast the `LPVOID` back to a pointer to your structure to use it.

Answer (score 6):

Put those arguments into a struct, allocated on the heap, and pass the address of the struct in the `LPVOID` parameter. Your thread function can then cast the `LPVOID` to a pointer to struct and read out the parameters.

It is essential that you put it on the heap because if you put it on the stack of the thread that calls `CreateThread` then it can be invalid by the time your thread procedure tries to access it.